# How to use IndexOf with Builders filter from mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to filter a collection like this

```
Builders<myClass>.Filter.Where(d => d.Name.IndexOf(".") > length)
```

but getting this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: {document}{Name}.IndexOf(".") is not supported.

Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that give:  `var indx1 = myString.IndexOf(myChar);` and `var indx2 = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf(myChar)).Length;` then indx1 = indx2

Comment: @Barns yes you are right, but indexOf is not supported neither

Comment: you have looked at the Mongodb docs? [LINQ](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/linq/) AND [LINQ Tutorial](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/linq/)

Comment: Yep read both documents but no clue

Answer (score 1):

you need a linq expression that can generate the following aggregation pipeline:

```cs
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [{ $indexOfCP: ['$name', '.'] }, 8]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

but no such strongly-typed method exists in the c# driver unfortunately.
as an alternative to dealing with `BsonDocuments`, have a look at [this](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/13.-String-Templates).